# Is there a referentially transparent way to work with times in php

Tags: php, time, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to convert times to and from the following timezones, regardless of when or where the code is run:

- The timezone of the running code
- AEST (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
- EDT (New York Eastern Daylight Time)

For example, given a unix timestamp, how do I find a new unix timestamp "monday the same week" using EDT timezone? How do I do this, such that it will always give the same result?

Comment: Is a database also involved? Or just PHP?

Comment: [This post is being discussed on meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309819/3367144)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best method for PHP Timezones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986453/best-method-for-php-timezones)

Answer (score 47):

First you have to understand that a Unix Timestamp has nothing to do with timezones, it is always relative to UTC/GMT. To quote from the manual

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Now that you know one timestamp represents a fixed time in reference to GMT/UTC you can go ahead and change time zones in your code to calculate time for them form the same timestamp.

Let us say you have a unix timestamp

```
$ts = 1171502725;
```

If you create a date from it you would do something like

```
$date = new DateTime("@$ts");
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "\n";
```

Now you want to see what does that correspond to in EST, you can do

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "\n";
```

Similarly for CST

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "\n";
```

And so on :)

**Output**

```
1171502725 = 2007-02-15 01:25:25 GMT+0000
1171502725 = 2007-02-14 20:25:25 EST
1171502725 = 2007-02-14 19:25:25 CST
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/463485)**

You can get a list of supported timezones and their identifiers from the **[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)**

Comment: micro-nitpick: (1) in general, "Unix Timestamp" counts only non-leap SI seconds in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15) e.g., 2 seconds elapsed between `2015-06-30 18:59:59 CST` and `2015-06-30 19:00:00 CST` (there is a leap second in between) but the POSIX time counts only 1 second. (2) In non-POSIX case, Unix timestamp may be different e.g., if `"right/UTC"` timezone is used then the timestamp represents actual elapsed SI seconds (TAI time scale, epoch: January 1 1970 00:00:10 TAI).

Comment: no. first you have to understand that I wanted EDT timezone, all year round.