# knowing timezones native offset (when DST is not active) in php

Tags: php, timezone

I want to list for the user, all timezones with their native UTC/GMT offset, regardless of DST

How can I do it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php  and
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a drop down list of timezones with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727077/generating-a-drop-down-list-of-timezones-with-php)

Comment: It is related, but seems that this particular question is not asked and not answered there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 've come up with this function to do the job:

```
function standard_tz_offset($timezone) {
    $now = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
    $year = $now->format('Y');

    $startOfYear = new DateTime('1/1/'.$year, $timezone);
    $startOfNext = new DateTime('1/1/'.($year + 1), $timezone);

    $transitions = $timezone->getTransitions($startOfYear->getTimestamp(),
                                             $startOfNext->getTimestamp());
    foreach($transitions as $transition) {
        if(!$transition['isdst']) {
            return $transition['offset'];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**How it works**

The function accepts a timezone and creates two `DateTime` objects: January 1st 00:00 of the current year and January 1st 00:00 of the next year, both specified in that timezone.

It then calculates the DST transitions during this year, and returns the offset for the first transition it finds where DST is not active.

**PHP 5.3 is required** because of the call to `DateTimeZone::getTransitions` with three parameters. If you want this to work in earlier versions you will have to accept a performance hit, because a whole lot of transitions will be generated by PHP (in this case, you don't need to bother with creating the `$startOfYear` and `$startOfNext` dates).

I have also tested this with timezones that do not observe DST (e.g. `Asia/Calcutta`) and it works for those as well.

**To test it:**

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Athens");
echo standard_tz_offset($timezone);
```

Comment: I hopped that something like this will not be needed, and also wasn't sure how do I work with the transitions. Thanks