# In PHP, how can I get Timezone from offset and country?

Tags: php, timezone

I am doing an IP lookup to determine a "best guess" for timezone offset from UTC and the country/region information.

So, for instance, I have offset -3 and country Brazil.

I want to show BRT instead of a random timezone in that same offset, i.e. ART

Is there some built-in way in PHP to be able to set the appropriate timezone with this information?

If not, what would be the easiest way to do this?
(Assume that I can't make any outside API calls)

If I do my own database table, how do I ensure it stays up to date?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think that timezones are changing all the time to where staying "up to date" is a major concern?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "major concern", but yes, they change frequently enough that I'm concerned.  Even in the United States, Indiana changed DST observation as recently as 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to roll your own database, here's one from [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/). You can also [get all the timezone information from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1727150/1493698).

Comment: Cool, thanks, this is good enough for my purposes.  I visited here when researching the answer, but didn't want to use their API and didn't see the downloadable data earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* resolve a timezone from an offset, or even an offset plus country.  See the `TimeZone != Offset` section of [the TimeZone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  The offsets have changed at many points in time, and they will inevitably change again.

You need more information, such as latitude/longitude.  See [this community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824).

If you can ask your user for their timezone, please do.  That's the best way.  My favorite UI for this is a JavaScript map-based timezone picker, [such as this one](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).  You can make a best-guess default choice using [jsTimeZoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect).

Answer (score 1):

This PHP function give back an array of all existing Timezones including Offset, not exactly what you are looking for but maybe it helps:

```
function time_zonelist(){
    $return = array();
    $timezone_identifiers_list = timezone_identifiers_list();
    foreach($timezone_identifiers_list as $timezone_identifier){
        $date_time_zone = new DateTimeZone($timezone_identifier);
        $date_time = new DateTime('now', $date_time_zone);
        $hours = floor($date_time_zone->getOffset($date_time) / 3600);
        $mins = floor(($date_time_zone->getOffset($date_time) - ($hours*3600)) / 60);
        $hours = 'GMT' . ($hours < 0 ? $hours : '+'.$hours);
        $mins = ($mins > 0 ? $mins : '0'.$mins);
        $text = str_replace("_"," ",$timezone_identifier);
        $return[$timezone_identifier] = $text.' ('.$hours.':'.$mins.')';
    }
    return $return;
}
```