# time difference in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create a simple application that will allow users to search for two locations and the time difference of two locations will be displayed to them.

I can get the two location Offset using the code bellow but I cannot hook it up to the form inputs so the users can choose the locations!

Here is what I have done so far:

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php $get_timezone_offset ?>">
  <label>
    <input type="text" class="timezone1"  id="timezone1" name="timezone1" id="timezone1" />
    <input type="text" class="timezone2"  id="timezone2" name="timezone2" id="timezone2" />
    <input name="" type="button" value="submit" />
  </label>
</form>

    <?php
    function get_timezone_offset( $origin_tz, $remote_tz ) {
        $timezone1 = new DateTimeZone( $origin_tz );
        $timezone2 = new DateTimeZone( $remote_tz );

        $datetime1 = new DateTime("now", $timezone1);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime("now", $timezone2);

        $offset = $timezone1->getOffset($datetime1) - $timezone2->getOffset($datetime2);
        return $offset;
    }

    $offset = get_timezone_offset( 'Europe/London', 'Asia/Shanghai' );

    // convert offset to hours
    echo $offset/3600;
    ?>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Are you having trouble parsing the form input and feeding it to the `get_timezone_offset` function?

Comment: You are explicitly  giving values to your function. As you have put Europe against Asia, you will recieve -7. if you want to put the form into it, you should pass $_POST['timezone1'] and 2 as arguements

Comment: @Technoh, Yes that is correct. basically what I want to do is to remove the 'Europe/London', 'Asia/Shanghai' which are timezone1 and timezone2 and let the users search for the location using the form provided in HTML format.

Comment: @SimonPresto if you have used google, you could type "php forms" and one of the first results is referring to PHP's official site: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php . Please, google before ask next time.

Comment: @RoyalBg, can you please give me a small example if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily remove the input and replace it with a dropdown list of all available timezones. The list of PHP supported timezones is available in the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). Then you could directly compare the values from one list to the other.

Also, see [Generating a drop down list of timezones with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727077/generating-a-drop-down-list-of-timezones-with-php), where someone made that list for you.

`DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);` will also create a list of available timezones.

Comment: well that is my issue. creating a dropdown list was the next stage that i was gonna follow but at the moment i need to know how I can "Compare the Values" be it in the input form or in a dropdown list!