# How to return timezone from dropdown list of countries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello I need to return timezones, when I select a country from a dropdown list.

Thank you!

Example

```
<select name='country' class='country'>
<option value='UK'>Ukraine</option>
<option value='RU'>Russian</option>
</select>
```

If choose UK ->alert(+2.0)
If choose RU ->alert(+4.0)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727077/generating-a-drop-down-list-of-timezones-with-php

Answer (score 0):

To find timezone you can use `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers`

Example, for Ukraine:

```
var_dump(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, "UK"));
```

So write `onChange` event using javasript and use PHP to get time zone.