# Set Middle East time-zone format in date-picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using JQuery datepicker ,I want to set middle east time format in date picker. which is 1.30 hours less than my time.How it is possible

My Jquery code is

```
$("#effectiveDateId").datepicker({
    inline: true,
    //nextText: '&rarr;',
    //prevText: '&larr;',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    //dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    //dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    //showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "img/calendar-blue.png",
    //buttonImageOnly: true,

    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope solve your problem after read out this

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
 [Generating a drop down list of timezones with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727077/generating-a-drop-down-list-of-timezones-with-php)

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)